# Running Giltab-runner on multiple servers

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

It's possible to use gitlab on one host and Gitlab-runner on other host. For example , I have ansible server on other host and I want to setup there gitlab-runner

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/):

> Ideally, the GitLab Runner should not be installed on the same machine
>   as GitLab. Read the [requirements documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html#gitlab-runner) for more information.